# Missing silent, vibrate or sound toggle on Lollipop's power button

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, power-options

The "silent, vibrate or normal sound" toggle function have changed somehow on my Nexus 5 to merely an "off" function when I hold down the power button. I'd like the old options back, but I can't find any settings dealing with the issue.

[image: pre-5.0] [image: 5.0]

<sup>Power options before & after Lollipop</sup>

Has it disappeared completely with the new "none, priority, all" slide?

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with Lollipop, please see the following:

[Issue 79445: No silent mode](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79445)

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is rooted, you can get the pre-Lollipop power options back:

1. Download [`power_menu.zip`](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3106037&d=1420795239), a mod by Ynych on XDA Forum.
2. Boot into custom recovery: press and hold <kbd>Volume down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> when the device is in powered-off state.
3. Install the mod by flashing the zip file.
4. Reboot the system.

[image: modded power options on Lollipop]

Source: [Bring Back Airplane Mode & Audio Toggles to Your Nexus 5's Power Menu - WonderHowTo](http://nexus5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/bring-back-airplane-mode-audio-toggles-your-nexus-5s-power-menu-0159661/)

Answer (score -1):

Update your phone to the latest android version (Marshmallow). With that you will be able to mute your phone again.

Be aware of apps that can play a sound and vibrate even when your phone is on mute.

Comment: Are you sure? I have Nexus 5 on Marshmallow, and I still only see "Power off" when holding the power button. Can you provide a screenshot?